# How to determine where a redirect to https is occurring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a site that, when accessed via `http`, gets auto redirected to `https`. We're trying to determine where this is occurring. So far we've looked in the following places:

- `.htaccess`
- in apache in the `httpd.conf`
- in the php file of a test page we wrote (site.com/test.php)

I'm thinking there could be some other `conf` file in apache that this redirect stuff would be occurring..

where else should I look?

Comment: Many distributions will have per-site Apache configuration files, too. For example, in Debian: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*

Comment: Maybe it was redirected before? Most browsers cache redirects.

Comment: Did you look in the file for your virtual hosting (if any)?

Comment: @JanKrüger we dont have a sites-enabled directory

Comment: @NickCaballero we have been clearing cache while testing

Comment: @Oliver we're looking into it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sites are served by a load balancer, it turns out that the redirect to https logic was actually being implemented at the load balancer level.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this same exact problem before. Did you take a look in your vhost file(s)?

Usually stored in /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/

My bet is you have a general rule to redirect such as www.google.com/cars/* will always redirect to https.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I had this error too until I find out, that for firefox it is useless to edit anything as long as the cache is active. Since then I deactivate the cache with the help of [web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/web-developer/).