# Unable to figure out where redirect is occurring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I read a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888664/how-to-determine-where-a-redirect-to-https-is-occurring) from someone who was having trouble figuring out where his redirect was occurring.

The main places that he checked were:

```
.htaccess
in apache in the httpd.conf
in the php file of a test page we wrote (site.com/test.php)
```

I am having a similar problem.  He found the solution on his own, but it does not apply to me.  I also tried some of the other suggestions such as /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/ to no avail.

I have a script /shop/login.php  that is throwing out a 302 redirect every time I try to access it.

I have checked the main places listed above, and cannot for the life of me figure out where this redirect is set up.

Any ideas on how I can figure this out?

Comment: .htaccess files can be littered all over - you'll have to check each directory all the way back up to the document root for one, not just the directory the script is in.

Comment: In unix I ran locate .htaccess, and then checked every .htaccess file that exists.  None of them contained the 302.

Comment: Actually I've been running recursive grep commands looking for "redirect" and "login.php".  I'm not finding anything.  I scanned the database too, to see if there was something set up in there.  Nada. :(

Comment: if it's php doing it, it'd probably be via `header('Location: ...')`, not "redirect". a header redirect may not actually list the script being redirected to, depending on how it's built.

Comment: I searched for 'location' on my local copy.  None of the entries were related to the login.php script.  Maybe I should enable a RewriteLog with Apache.  Would that tell me exactly where the rewrite is occurring?

Comment: only if it's mod_rewrite doing the redirect, and you'd have seen that when going through the .conf/.htaccess files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  There were several redirects.  The routes, the actions, the php code...

I had to follow the maze until it was all untangled.

Sorry for asking a question that probably nobody could answer without having access to the entire site.  I didn't realize that it would be that difficult.

Thanks all for your help!